# Clang-Format struggeling with `std::visit` and templated struct

Tags: c++, clang-format

Consider the following `clang-format` file:

```
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  Google
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: None
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: None
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: No
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 0
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
ForEachMacros:   [ foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH ]
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
IndentCaseLabels: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
PointerAlignment: Left
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 200
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 5000
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 400
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    CaseSensitive
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 4
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        c++20
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          Never
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
PackConstructorInitializers: CurrentLine
```

I have two piece of code that get formatted very weirdly and I don't really understand why.

1.

```cpp
//see example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

std::visit(overloaded
    {
            [](std::monostate) -> std::optional<SomeType> { throw std::runtime_error("unexpected monostate");},
            [](auto & c) -> std::optional<SomeType> { return c.foo(); }
    }, some_variant);
```

gets formatted into

```
std::visit(overloaded{[](std::monostate) -> std::optional<SomeType> {
                                     throw std::runtime_error(
                                     "unexpected monostate");
                                 },
                                 [](auto& c) -> std::optional<SomeType>
                                 { return c.foo(); }},
                      some_variant);
```

I don't understand how the spacing here gets created at all. Like how does the throw get moved to that position?

2.

```
template<typename F, typename G>
void f(int i, F f, G g)
{}

int veryLongParameterNAme;
f(veryLongParameterNAme, []() { int i = 9; }, []() { int j = 0; });
```

becomes

```
template<typename F, typename G> void f(int i, F f, G g)
{
}

int veryLongParameterNAme;
f(
veryLongParameterNAme, []() { int i = 9; }, []() { int j = 0; });
```

Why is there a new line after the `f(`? Can this be removed? Can we add a new line after the `template<...>` statement?

Any help here is appreciated! These are the only things I was not really able to solve with just searching on StackOverflow...

Comment: One part of the answer is to set 'AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations' to 'Yes'. But using the `f(overload{ <lambda>, <lambda> ... })` pattern is a pain with clang-format. After struggling with it for a while I resorted to always wrapping expressions like these with `// clang-format off` / `clang-format on`.

Comment: Try add extra comma after last lambda before closing `}` for `overloaded`. It helps in case of arrays and initialization list. It compiles fine, maybe clang-format will behave like you want. https://godbolt.org/z/bb34TYvqa

Comment: @chrysante Thanks a lot for the suggestion and the confirmation that this is not as straight forward as I had hoped.

Comment: @MarekR That already helped a bit. The formatting looks better, but still not as I would expect it.